# Xcode git merged with master, cannot find any files

Tags: xcode, git

I merged one of my branches into master through Xcode. As soon as I did, all of my files in the project navigator disappeared.

Git in terminal has run me through loops trying to revert back to a previous commit.

I am relatively new to git, so could someone please guide me through the correct process of A) retrieving my files, and (if someone feels like being incredibly helpful) B) properly adding/merging a branch into the master branch?

**EDIT**

The `.xcodeproj` file is still intact and usable with the correct files, it is the `.xcworkspace` file I have been using (as a result of `cocoa pods`) that no longer contains any of the appropriate files.

So within the `.xcworkspace` file, I can no longer access the scheme or find any of the files or utilize source control.

Comment: Your project.pbxproj/.xcodeproj file must not be merged correctly. That's why no file is showing. From external source like source tree, try to look into that file.

Comment: @NightFury I have edited my question for clarification. And I have done some digging into the source files but haven't been able to find a culprit that would lead to a solution yet.

Comment: Did you revert back to previous commit?

Comment: Whenever I attempt to revert git tells me I have unmerged files. Which stumps me, because as far as I can tell, everything has been merged.

Comment: Xcode always has such issues, due to some project files states. Just to make things easy for yourself, download source tree and discard all changes and merges made

Comment: Will source tree be able to help even though I have been using a local git repository, instead of github itself?

Comment: Source tree has nice GUI to help with source management. You can use any local/remote repo there

Comment: @NightFury after playing around with source tree, I managed to recover my old files. Thank you! If you would make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem - before I post an answer, did you happen to modify the .pbxproj file?

Comment: @ArielSD, I don't recall if I made any changes to the .pbxproj file. It's been several months since I worked on the project. But I ended up using Source Tree to recover the files and properly merge into Master, which fixed my problems. I still don't know what caused the issue in the first place...